# How to use sideEffect and dedup in a Gremlin traversal?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

## Background

We're trying to build up a query such that for a given `label` we want to get *all* of the neighbors of that `label` type for a list of ids. We have about 5 different labels, so we're building up a traversal to do it all in a single query.

## Goal

We want to ensure that for a given `label`, we query N neighbors and for all the aggregated neighbors in the `idsToBatchQuery` list, we dedupe them all.

The problem we're facing is that the side-effect is only deduping for each vertex.
For example - If we have 10 vertices in the `idsToBatchQuery` list and each vertex has 3 neighbors, we only dedupe across those 3 neighbors instead of deduping the 30 complete list of neighbors.

## Question

How can we modify the below query to grab the first `maxBreadth` unique neighbors from all the vertices in `idsToBatchQuery`?

```
        var traversal = g.V(idsToBatchQuery.toArray())

        for (String label : labels) {
          traversal =
              traversal.sideEffect(
                  outE(EDGE_LABEL)
                      .inV()
                      .hasLabel(label)
                      .dedup()
                      .by(T.id)
                      .limit(maxBreadth)
                      .aggregate(label));
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps replace `dedup` with `where(without(label))`

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer below showing this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [air-routes](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/tree/master/sample-data) data set, here is a similar query, but the `dedup` step has been replaced with `where(without('labels'))`. This gives a more global deduplication across all values seen not just the two "local" ones.

```java
g.V('1','2','3','56').
  sideEffect(
    outE('route').
    inV().
    hasLabel('airport').
    where(without('labels')).
    limit(2).
    aggregate('labels')).
  sideEffect(
    inE('contains').
    outV().
    hasLabel('country').
    where(without('labels')).
    limit(2).
    aggregate('labels')).
  cap('labels').
  unfold().
  values('desc')
```

Here's the output from running the query. The results would have had duplicates had `dedup` been used instead as in your original query.

```
1   Ontario International Airport
2   Greater Rochester International Airport
3   United States
4   Fairbanks International Airport
5   Reykjavik, Keflavik International Airport
6   Charlotte Douglas International Airport
7   Cancun International Airport
8   Phnom Penh International Airport
9   Gold Coast Airport
10  Singapore
```

If the original `dedup` is used, you can see that there are duplicates in the results.

```
1   Ontario International Airport
2   Ontario International Airport
3   Greater Rochester International Airport
4   United States
5   United States
6   United States
7   Fairbanks International Airport
8   Reykjavik, Keflavik International Airport
9   Charlotte Douglas International Airport
10  Phnom Penh International Airport
```